# How to set up an application level variable in Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have this list :

```
List<string> stationNames = new List<string>() { "First station", "Second station" };
```

And I would like it to be accesible from all pages of my app if it is possible. How could i do that ? I could set it up on every one of my pages, but i don't think this is the most efficient way.

Comment: Create a Public Class in which define `stationNames` as property and you can access this stationNames from anywhere

Comment: If the data is static (ie doesn't change), why don't you create store them in a Setting?

Comment: Where would the values come from? Are they hard-coded, do they come from a settings file? Can they be modified at runtime or are they read-only, in which case an array would be better?

Comment: The values are static and they cannot be modified.

Comment: Then why don't you put them in settings? The Settings class *is* visible to the entire application

Comment: Alright i think i got it, i will put the list in settings. Just one more question. What if the list contains around 1000 elements? Would it be a better idea to put it in a database ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **public static** property.

In one of your classes, define it as such:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static readonly List<string> stationNames = new List<string> { "First station", "Second station" };
}
```

Since static properties are not associated with any instance, you can access it from anywhere using:

```
MyClass.stationNames
```

*Edit:* I added the **readonly** modifier to the List because, as Panagiotis pointed out below, this would not allow the List to be modified at some other time. However, if that is your intended behaviour, don't include the readonly modifier.

Comment: Global/static fields or properties are generally frowned upon, even though that's what the OP asked. This is a good answer given how the question is worded, but it should be avoided in production code. You could improve it by defining it as `readonly` so that code can't overwrite it or change it to an array (same reason)

Answer (score 0):

I think that using static field with the list in the app is not quite good idea.
If this data will not change and should be read-only you can use ApplicationData class. Please see below:

1. To save the list in the settings you should execute below code:

   ```
   var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
   localSettings.Values["Stations"] = new List<string> { "First station", "Second station" };
   ```
2. To retrieve the list:

   ```
   var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
   List<string> stationNames = (List<string>) localSettings.Values["Stations"];
   ```